# iOS: Mobile Device Management

Tags: iphone, ios4, apple-push-notifications, mdm

I am little confused about the MDM, wish that someone could help me here. I have studied the docs from the Apple website regarding the iOS MDM,but still I feel puzzled ,I have some questions.

1. Whether MDM server is communicating APNS every-time when it needs to execute command ?
2. Is it very complex to setup our own MDM server and how to setup our own MDM server ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Reference link for iOS MDM http://iosmdm.blogspot.in

Comment: How many users is this for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) the general idea is that you send one request via APNS and then respond with a command when the device 'phones home' to your MDM server. Once the device responds to your command, you can send another command back in response and so on until the device has executed all the commands at which point your server should respond with an empty HTTP response.

2) That entirely depends on what your definition of complex is! I have created 2 MDM 'servers' in the past year and it's not impossible but quite complex to detail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir ! Its cool that you have created 2 MDM servers . Gr8.


So I guess, whenever the MDM server needs to send some command, it will make an HTTP session with device by sending a notification via APNS, am i right :)

Comment: Can you tell me how to Setup a MDM server? For your info , i have went through some related docs from Blackhat,etc.

Comment: Correct, you need to communicate with APNS to have the device talk back to your MDM server. As for setting up an MDM server, the best docs are from Apple and they are available via the provisioning portal if you have an enterprise account - otherwise, you will have to email Apple and ask for them.

Comment: Also what you will find is that people who know about MDM are usually under an NDA with Apple so getting detailed information is going to prove to be problematic.

Comment: I have an enterprise account and i have went through the protocol documents too. I am looking for some example how it works internally(by practical) And you are right that its hard to find some information to setup a MDM server. :( . Aint i find any breakthrough for setting up an own MDM server ???? :( :(

Comment: Unfortunately the comments aren't the best way to help out here - can you ping me your email address and I'll try my best to craft a more detailed response.

Answer (score 0):

MDM server communicates only when it needs to send a command to the device.
Here is how it goes,

1. MDM server contacts APNS server with MDM payload.
2. APNS server triggers a wake up on device to check server for MDM command.
3. Mobile device contacts the MDM server for command to be executed.

Implementing MDM is simple if you have a enterprise account.

1. Get your MDM certificate.
   http://www.blueboxmoon.com/wordpress/?p=877
2. Using IPCU create a profile and push it on mobile.
3. With this the device push magic will be passed to the checkin URL you specified in the config profile.
4. Then trigger the mdm payload using JAVAPNS with push magic and token.
   JavaPNS - https://code.google.com/p/javapns/
5. Create a simple page that will respond to device command.
   Refer Blackhat guide for full documentation.
   https://media.blackhat.com/bh-us-11/Schuetz/BH_US_11_Schuetz_InsideAppleMDM_WP.pdf
   or this http://darthnull.org/media/papers/MDM_CommandReference.pdf for commands reference.